# How to require Java.inc in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, php-java-bridge

I configure Java bridge with tomcat. Which is accessible in  `http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc`.

In core php we use require_once to include file. `require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
$myObj = new Java("com.fss.plugin.iPayPipe");`

It works fine in core PHP. But it is not work in Laravel.

It shows an error `Class 'Java' not found`.

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at what is displayed when you open `http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc` in a browser - is it PHP code? If yes, try to output the result on your webserver through `echo file_get_contents("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");` - is that still PHP code?

Maybe there is an import you are missing - if the `Java` class is not in a namespace, but your Lavarel code is, you should instantiate the class using `$myObj = new \Java(...)`

Comment: Thanks its working.. actually i forgot to instantiate the class 'Java'. I change to '\Java' .